# How to add apps shortcuts to Android homescreen in AOSP build

Tags: android, build, android-source, shortcut

I am building my own custom Android image from AOSP source code, and I would like to add shortcuts of the apps I am installing by default from compilation but I haven't found anything about how to do this.
I have searched in the AOSP source code but I did not see anything useful: is there an specific file or way to add apps shortcuts from AOSP compilation?